# no member named 'Tensor' in namespace 'Eigen'

Tags: macos, tensor, clang++

I can't manage to use Eigen::Tensor objects.
Here is my main

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  Eigen::Tensor<int, 2> a(2, 3);
}
```

and I get this error when compiling:

```
test_tensor_eigen.cpp:8:10: error: no member named 'Tensor' in namespace 'Eigen'
  Eigen::Tensor<int, 2> a(2, 3);
  ~~~~~~~^
```

Mac M1, eigen 3.4.0_1 was installed with homebrew, the compilation is runned through

`clang++ -I /opt/homebrew/include/eigen3  test_tensor_eigen.cpp`

I have tried to reinstall eigen3.

Comment: The solution is : 
clang++ -std=c++11 -I /opt/homebrew/include/eigen3  test_tensor_eigen.cpp